# Proof of ⊨∃x(Px⇒∀xPx) (Drinker's Paradox)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

⊨∃x(Px⇒∀xPx)
I was trying to solve the above drinker's paradox by contradiction and came up with the below expression by negating the above expression -

⊨ ∀x ( Px ∧ ¬ ∀x Px )

This is where I got stuck because to distribute the universal quantifier I need all the variables inside the parenthesis to be bound variables but as x is a free variable I was not able to go further.
Is the approach correct considering that the universal set is not empty and what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, you have not given an equivalent expression, but rather the negation of the expression.

You can however equivalenty write it as $\models \exists x (\neg Px \lor \forall y Py)$

It should be quite clear why this is true. Just read it out. "There is an $x$ such that either $Px$ is false, or $Px$ is true for all $x$. This is evident by just considering the two cases of when $Px$ is true for all $x$ and when it is not.

Comment: I have updated my question a little just for the language. Can i solve it through contradiction? And if yes then how?

Comment: @Random Yup. Since the x in the second term is not bound by the x in the first quantifier, you can pull it out and you get $\forall x Px \land \neg(\forall x Px)$ which is a contradiction